# *** Assertion failure in -[Scrapboom.iPhone.NewsFeedTableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:1076

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am using below code in UITablViewSource

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
 {
 UIImage scaledImage=null;
string cellIdentifier = "NewsFeedCell"; 
var newsFeedCellItem = NewsFeedCellItemList [indexPath.Row];    
var newsFeedCell = new NewsFeedCell (NewsFeedScreenInstance, newsFeedCellItem,       cellIdentifier, indexPath);

if (newsFeedCell != null) {
 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (newsFeedCellItem.FeedItem.Picture.PreviewUrl)) {
                var image = ImageStore.Get      (newsFeedCellItem.FeedItem.Picture.PreviewUrl);
                if(image != null)
                {
                    newsFeedCellItem.FeedItem.Picture.Image = image;
                    scaledImage = ImageHelper.Scale(image, new SizeF (528, 528));
                }
                if (scaledImage != null) {
                    newsFeedCell.ScrapImage = scaledImage;
                } else {
                    BeginDownloadImage (tableView, indexPath);
                }

            }


        }

        return newsFeedCell;
    }

    #endregion

    #region PRIVATE METHODS

    private void BeginDownloadImage (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Action successAction = () => {

            this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                tableView.BeginUpdates ();
                tableView.ReloadRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                tableView.EndUpdates ();
            });
        };

        ImageStore.BeginDownloadImage(NewsFeedCellItemList [indexPath.Row].FeedItem.Picture.PreviewUrl, successAction);
    }
    #endregion
```

**Description:**But below part of code is giving exception as

> *** Assertion failure in -[Scrapboom.iPhone.NewsFeedTableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:1076 and application is
>   get hanged or sometimes crashing.

```
tableView.ReloadRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetCell` implementation looks wrong. You should try to `Dequeue` a cell, then create one if it fails (not even required in iOS6+ with `Register*ForCellReuse`:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    string cellIdentifier = "NewsFeedCell"; 
    var newsFeedCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as NewsFeedCell;

    //only required if you haven't used Register*ForCellReuse
    if (newsFeedCell == null)
        newsFeedCell = new NewsFeedCell (..., cellIdentifier,...);

    //update your cell image and components here.
}
```

To know more about this, read the [tutorials](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_3_-_customizing_a_table%27s_appearance).

If you look around, you'll also find proven working patterns to load images in table cells lazily. Not that yours looks wrong at first sight, but it's uncommon.

Comment: NewsFeedCell newsFeedCell= tableView.CellAt (indexPath) as NewsFeedCell;                                                              Above code is returning newsFeedCell=null

Comment: that's possible, if it's not on view anymore. that is, the cell has been recycled. in that case, you don't even have ot bother about dsplaying the image.